# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project fhirql: Fatal error compiling

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I run the command mvn clean package I got above error my pom is:

[image]

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
    <artifactId>hapi-fhir</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.canehealth</groupId>
<artifactId>fhirql</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>EEE, MMM dd yyyy, HH:mm Z</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Compile -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-fhir-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-fhir-jpaserver-base</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-fhir-jaxrsserver-base</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Added -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-fhir-client</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-fhir-structures-dstu3</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-fhir-testpage-overlay</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-fhir-testpage-overlay</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        <classifier>classes</classifier>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Optional -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-fhir-spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
        <artifactId>hapi-fhir-base</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>ca.uhn.hapi.fhir</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hapi-fhir-testpage-overlay</artifactId>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.11</source>
                <target>1.11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Remove the compiler plugin. And use 11 as the java version.

Comment: Also remove the maven-war-plugin does not make sense to create a war within a jar packaging type...

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same issue, it works for me after changing version 11 to 1.8,

replace

```html
<properties>
   <java.version>11</java.version>
  </properties>
```

with

```html
<properties>
   <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>
```

Comment: What if I have to use JDK 11?

Answer (score 5):

Since you have not pasted the complete error i believe you might have got below error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project demo: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 1.11 -
```

For maven compiler the correct JDK version is `1.8`, `1.9`, `1.10`, `11`, `12` ..

You could also simply replace the above `<properties>` tag with below

```
    <properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
   </properties>
```

I have taken the above one from a sample project from Spring Initializr. 
You can remove the configuration from the maven compiler plugin too.

Comment: I tried but same error.. could you give a try.          https://filebin.net/w1qz6i8jsnqrtv41

Answer (score 1):

You can change `maven.compiler.target` version from `1.11` to `11`

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
</properties>
```